# Error in Updating a table using datetime as parameter in Stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datetime

The conversion of a char data type to a DateTime data type resulted in an out-of-range DateTime value.
The statement has been terminated.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[attendance_updatebyemployee_id]
@Employee_id int,
@AtDate datetime,
@FNLogged bit,
@ANLogged bit,
@LogTime varchar(10),
@LogOuttime varchar(10) 

AS
BEGIN   


    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
    update Mst_Attendance set FNLogged=@FNLogged,
    ANLogged=@ANLogged,LogTime=@LogTime,LogOuttime=@LogOuttime 
    where EmployeeId=@Employee_id and Atdate= @AtDate

END
```

in C# Code i give it as

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AtDate",Dtime.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));
```

while using SQl profiler.the data passed is

```
exec [dbo].[attendance_updatebyemployee_id] @Employee_id=2,@AtDate='Feb 19 2011 12:00:00:000AM',@FNLogged=1,@ANLogged=0,@LogTime='11:45 AM',@LogOuttime=' '
```

inside the stored procedure the @AtDate has value `2011-02-19 00:00:00.000.`
it is breaking from the update command.

Inside the table the date is saved as `2/19/2011 12:00:00 AM`

How can i solve this date problem.

Comment: can you please post the code or error message. so that we can avoid a guessed solution!

Comment: Please post relevant code, it would help.

Comment: At the very least you could try off the top to convet your char to a string and pass it that way or put it in a try catch a tell the exception if you don't feel like showing your code for whatever reason.

Comment: You're not asking this question the smart way. You should post the *exact* error message you get, along with a snippet of the exact code you're using so that we can reproduce the problem ourselves. At this point, your question is virtually unanswerable. There are too many "possible" ways for things to go wrong.

Comment: More than likely your char string doesn't match the default datetime format. Try specifying the date format.

Comment: if it was for SQL you should have changed you Tags and mention that in your question.. well i have changed it

Comment: updated my asnwer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049173/error-in-updating-a-table-using-datetime-as-parameter-in-stored-procedure/5049198#5049198

Comment: Why use varchar in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the tool use the [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) to actually see the **exact** SQL string that is passed to the database. This will help you to find the error.

Comment: while using SQl profiler.the data passed is exec [dbo].[attendance_updatebyemployee_id] @Employee_id=2,@AtDate='Feb 19 2011 12:00:00:000AM',@FNLogged=1,@ANLogged=0,@LogTime='11:45 AM',@LogOuttime=' '

Comment: Add this to the question, that will help you to get an answer. For even better results show the client code as well. It looks like you did a ToString() or ToShortDateTime() on a DateTime type. Don't do that. Just pass the DateTime, ADO will convert it. SQL Server might be chocking on the spaces instead of slashes.

Comment: You marked this as the answer, please tell us (comment on this answer) the answer you found so others can profit.

Answer (score 5):

From your code, it seems you have a `DateTime` variable in your C# code - so just use that as is - there's absolutely no need to convert to a string!!

If you have:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[attendance_updatebyemployee_id]
  @Employee_id int,
  @AtDate datetime,
.....
```

then you can call this stored like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AtDate", Dtime);
```

assuming `Dtime` is of type `DateTime` in C#.

Don't convert and cast stuff unnecessarily! This only introduces potential breakages and conversion errors! Just use the `DateTime` as is - it will be sent to SQL Server and used and recognized as a `DATETIME` in T-SQL.

And if you really do need to convert a date value to a string for passing it to SQL Server, I would **always** recommend using the ISO-8601 standard format: `YYYYMMDD` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` which is recognized and works regardless of any regional, language or locale settings.

So if you absolutely must, then use:

```
Dtime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

or

```
Dtime.ToString("yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss")
```

and nothing else (all other formats are language- and setting-dependent and might work in one case, and break in another; ISO-8601 **always** works)

Comment: update Mst_Attendance set FNLogged=@FNLogged,
   ANLogged=@ANLogged,LogTime=@LogTime,LogOuttime=@LogOuttime 
   where EmployeeId=@Employee_id and Atdate = FORMAT(@AtDate,'MM/DD/YYYY').Error on 'FORMAT' is not a recognised built in function name

Comment: @aswathi: please **DO NOT** post code and stuff like that in a comment - it's nearly impossible to read and understand. Please **update** your original question by **editing** it if you need to provide more info!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

You formatting string should be as

```
ToString("MM\\/dd\\/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

this will give output as in your database

```
02/19/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

---

You can use [DateTime.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) to convert a string to a DateTime object.

However you need to ensure that string is infact a datetime representation.

**Example (From MSDN)**

```
string[] dateStrings = {"05/01/2009 14:57:32.8", "2009-05-01 14:57:32.8", 
                        "2009-05-01T14:57:32.8375298-04:00", 
                        "5/01/2008 14:57:32.80 -07:00", 
                        "1 May 2008 2:57:32.8 PM", "16-05-2009 1:00:32 PM", 
                        "Fri, 15 May 2009 20:10:57 GMT" };
DateTime dateValue;

Console.WriteLine("Attempting to parse strings using {0} culture.", 
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
{
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)) 
    Console.WriteLine("  Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, 
                        dateValue, dateValue.Kind);
else
    Console.WriteLine("  Unable to parse '{0}'.", dateString);
}
// The example displays the following output:
//    Attempting to parse strings using en-US culture.
//       Converted '05/01/2009 14:57:32.8' to 5/1/2009 2:57:32 PM (Unspecified).
//       Converted '2009-05-01 14:57:32.8' to 5/1/2009 2:57:32 PM (Unspecified).
//       Converted '2009-05-01T14:57:32.8375298-04:00' to 5/1/2009 11:57:32 AM (Local).
//       Converted '5/01/2008 14:57:32.80 -07:00' to 5/1/2008 2:57:32 PM (Local).
//       Converted '1 May 2008 2:57:32.8 PM' to 5/1/2008 2:57:32 PM (Unspecified).
//       Unable to parse '16-05-2009 1:00:32 PM'.
//       Converted 'Fri, 15 May 2009 20:10:57 GMT' to 5/15/2009 1:10:57 PM (Local).
```

---

If you know what is the format of the date you are trying to Parse then you can use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) and specify your formatting in the second parameter:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm", enUS, 
                         DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue)
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with parsing the date.i checked all formats while debugging the stored procedure.but it is showing the same error when executing the update command.

Comment: Oh ita was for SQL you didn't mentioned that before.. any way can you show us a sample DateTime string you are trying to parse

Answer (score 0):

Its just a matter of matching the data type in 3 places:

- The type your C# passes to the Stored Procedure
- The type your Store Procedure is expecting it
- The type you field is in the database

Currently,

- You C# is passing a **string** value `Dtime.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")`
- Your Stored Procedure is expecting a **datetime** (`@AtDate datetime`)
- Your `Atdate` field in database seems to be **datetime** (`Atdate=@AtDate`)

So, to make them all match, you only have to adjust your C# code, from string to Dtime, like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AtDate",Dtime);
```

And i hope the Atdate field in your database is actually a DATETIME, not a VARCHAR. If it is a VARCHAR, then you should keep your C# code as it is, and change the @AtDate parameter in the Stored Procedure match it:

```
@AtDate VARCHAR(10)
```

But the best, if possible, is to make them all a true DATETIME. Avoid using strings (varchar) for dates if you can