# Error in Updating a table using Stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net

In this stored procedure there is an error occured. That is 'format' is not a recognized built in function name

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[attendance_updatebyemployee_id]
@Employee_id int,
@AtDate datetime,
@FNLogged bit,
@ANLogged bit,
@LogTime varchar(10),
@LogOuttime varchar(10) 
AS
BEGIN   

select @AtDate 



SET NOCOUNT ON;    
    update Mst_Attendance set FNLogged=@FNLogged,
   ANLogged=@ANLogged,LogTime=@LogTime,LogOuttime=@LogOuttime 
   where EmployeeId=@Employee_id and Atdate = FORMAT(@AtDate,'MM/DD/YYYY')

select * from Mst_Attendance where Atdate=@AtDate and EmployeeId=@Employee_id


END
```

Comment: If your `AtDate` column also is of type `DATETIME` (which I surely hope it is!), then you don't need any formatting/converting at all - just compare `and AtDate = @AtDate` - keep it simple and easy! A `DATETIME` is always a `DATETIME` is a `DATETIME` - no formatting/converting/messign around needed ! Just use it as is...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in Updating a table using datetime as parameter in Stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049173/error-in-updating-a-table-using-datetime-as-parameter-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: why are you asking the same question again???

Comment: Fix your database: it's poor design to use varchar() to store datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @AtDate, 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

However, surely your AtDate column should be a datetime?

Comment: there is also an error on AS [MM/DD/YYYY].Incorrect syntax near AS

Comment: AtDate column  is smalldatetime

Answer (score 1):

What database and version are you using? By the syntax, I assume it is MS SQL Server, but what version? 2000, 2008?

In MS SQL Server, there is no `FORMAT` function. But you can use `CONVERT`.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @AtDate ,101)
```

101 here means 'MM/DD/YYYY'. For other formats, check the [Official SQL Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Im assuming you `Atdate` field in the database is a VARCHAR(10) (or else you wouldnt need any convertion at all). But i strongly advise against that. Whenever possible, use `DATETIME` for dates, **not** VARCHAR

Comment: @aswathi: you just said in a comment that AtDate is SMALLDATETIME in the database, right? Then no **conversion is needed AT ALL**. Just remove the FORMAT and CONVERT from the stored procedure, AND also the .toString from your C# code, and it will work

Answer (score 0):

`FORMAT()` is **not** a SQL Server built-in function.

You can do it like this:

```
update Mst_Attendance 
set 
    FNLogged=@FNLogged, ANLogged=@ANLogged, 
    LogTime=@LogTime, LogOuttime=@LogOuttime     
where 
    EmployeeId=@Employee_id AND
    Atdate = @AtDate
```

Please tell me that your `Atdate` column is a `datetime` and NOT a `varchar()`

Comment: this procedure return an incorrect value.That is i want date format dd/mm/yyyy.but get a mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to output a DateTime column as a string in MM/DD/YY format:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, @AtDate, 1)
```

However this is not necessary in your query as the column appears to be a DateTime type already.

More built in date conversion formats:

http://www.technoreader.com/SQL-Server-Date-Time-Format.aspx

Comment: OP is not outputting a datetime; rather they are filtering with it.